# No Card Drops Remaining for CSGO

Tags: steam, pc, counter-strike-global-offensive

Does CSGO drop random trading cards? I'm asking this because I never got any card drops and I have 90 hours playtime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like many other games CS:GO drops cards if you purchased the game (which is not relevant since it is free for some time now) or spent some money on in-game purchases. This is what I see if I open my existing CS:GO badge:

[image]

So you need to spend about $9 to get a card.